# How to make JUnit with mockito on delete

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, mockito, powermock

i need a little help from you guys.

i want to make testing for this code :

```
//Delete - Patient
void deletePatient(long id) throws PatientNotFoundException {
    long deletedRecord = clientWrapperWrite.deleteSingle(PATIENT_COLLECTION_NAME, id);
    if (deletedRecord == 0) {
        throw new PatientNotFoundException(id);
    }
}
```

And this is what i did for the test

```
   //Delete Patient TestUnit - OnProgress (SOS)
@Test
public void deletingEmptyPatient() throws PatientNotFoundException, IOException {
    MongoClientWrapper mockClientWrapperWrite = mock(MongoClientWrapper.class);
    MongoClientWrapper mockClientWrapperRead = mock(MongoClientWrapper.class);
    when(mockClientWrapperRead.getSingle("patient",10001L)).thenReturn(createSinglePatient().toJson());
    Patient dummyPatient = createSinglePatient();

    myPatientFacade = MyPatientFacadeBuilder.create("conf/mypatient-server-test.properties")
            .withMongoClientWrapperRead(mockClientWrapperRead)
            .withMongoClientWrapperWrite(mockClientWrapperWrite)
            .build();

    myPatientFacade.addSinglePatient(dummyPatient);
    myPatientFacade.deletePatient(10001L);

    thrownException.expect(PatientVisitNotFoundException.class);
    thrownException.expectMessage("Patient ID '10001' cannot be found.");

    verify(mockClientWrapperWrite,times(1))
           .deleteSingle("patient",10001L);

}
```

Im still learning how to learn using JUnit and mockito. Please guide me.
Thank you for stopping by, have a nice day

============================================================================

Update :

So, the error was saying `com.at.mypatient.cosmed.exceptions.PatientNotFoundException: Patient ID '10001' cannot be found.`

what i want to make, the unit making the simulator of the patient then run the delete and verify the delete.

Comment: It seems you forgot to add what the debugger told you? If you have a stacktrace you might want to add it. On the ohter hand I have to agree with `@SwaritAgarwal` and you are better of writing a `IntegrationTest` for this one.

Comment: Please avoid adding images of text to your question. Instead copy paste the stacktrace directly. That said: You have not defined any behaviour on your mock, so `clientWrapperWrite.deleteSingle` will return 0 which triggers your exception.

Comment: How is behaving different to how you expect? Please attach text containing the test output, and say what you expect.

Comment: Looks like you define the behaviour on the wrong mock, use `mockClientWrapperWrite` instead. Also make sure that your dummyPatient has the id `10001L`.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly use **H2 or HSQL** and prepare separate layer on repository layer test cases instead coming from controller layer.

Follow steps

- Insert one record
- select record (size should be greater than 1)
- Delete respective record
- select record and verify (size zero or empty exception)

Happy to help further